# Is it possible to set base_estimator as OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier()) for Adaboost?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, adaboost

I'm trying to build an Adaboost model on a dataset with multiclass labels on age group and ethnic group.

As I'm planning to get the ROC and AUC, so I binarized the target variables as yb_train2 for age group and yb_train3 for ethnic group. Then I tried one-vs-rest in decision tree model, which works fine.

but now I have no idea how to specify the parameters in the grid search, I tried the following code, and get a syntax error:

```
abc = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator= (OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier()))


param_grid = dict(base_estimator__estimator__criterion = ["gini", "entropy"],
                  base_estimator__estimator__splitter = ["best", "random"],
                  n_estimators = [1, 2],
                  learning_rate =  [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1]
                  )

grid = GridSearchCV(abc,param_grid)

grid.fit(X_train,yb_train2)
print ('best score: {:}').format(grid.best_score_ ), ('with parameter: {:}').format(grid.best_params_)

grid.fit(X_train,yb_train3)
print ('best score: {:}').format(grid.best_score_ ), ('with parameter:{:}').format(grid.best_params_)
```

[image]
Can somebody give some suggestions in this kind of situation? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to close one of the brackets.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

abc = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator= (OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())))

param_grid = dict(base_estimator__estimator__criterion = ["gini", "entropy"],
                  base_estimator__estimator__splitter = ["best", "random"],
                  n_estimators = [1, 2],
                  learning_rate =  [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,1]
                  )

grid = GridSearchCV(abc,param_grid)
```

This can help you overcome the syntax error.

But DecisionTreeClassifier are by default multi-class classifiers hence I would suggest not to use oneVsRestclassifier wrapper on top of it.

Comment: Thanks bro, got this fixed. but still cannot input binarized multiclass data. it will return 'ValueError: bad input shape (72, 5)' after I fit the grid to my data which have 5 classes. Shall I do OneRestClassifer(Adaboost()) instead of put Adaboost() out of brackets? but how can I specify the parameters for each? OMG!! that's sooo complicated.. but anyway, thanks for the help with the fix.

Comment: My point is that you dont have to binarize the multiclass data. You can directly feed that to decisionTreeClassifier or Adaboost

Comment: Cos I'm using ROC as classification metrics for all my models, as the ROC needs to binarize the data, so that's why I'm trying to figure out this problem

Comment: @Venkatachalam When we use another classifier as a base estimator for AdaBoost do we then not need to use AdaBoost's own `n_estimators` and `learning_rate?` params? What's the convention?

Comment: I think that you still need to provide the n_estimate and learning_rate, which works across iterations in Adaboost.